# Android, draw path on canvas. How to extract path from image?

Tags: android, image, canvas

I want to extract a path from a png image and then draw it on an Android canvas. I know how to draw things in Android. What I need to learn is a good workflow for creating paths in order to draw them. I don't need the procedure to be dynamic. For example, I draw a path in a cad software, I get all the points' coordinates and then convert it to Android path.

Any ideas, a workflow, a dedicated tool will be appreciated?

Comment: Maybe its late but you can use garphics software or such to see and get the positions for your path and use it.